# Jenkins node setup is failing with jdk directory not found

Tags: jenkins

I am setting up a new node in Jenkins and have set up the JDK and exported it in the "PATH" as well ".bashrc".

```
[gautashe@centos8 jvm]$ cat ~/.bashrc | tail -4
# User specific aliases and functions
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.9-0.3.ea.el8.x86_64
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

```
[gautashe@centos8 ~]$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.18-ea" 2023-01-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.18.0.9-0.3.ea.el8) (build 11.0.18-ea+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.18.0.9-0.3.ea.el8) (build 11.0.18-ea+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
[gautashe@centos8 ~]$
[gautashe@centos8 ~]$
[gautashe@centos8 ~]$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

while launching a new node on Jenkins failing with the below exception,

Jenkins node logs,

```
[01/25/24 01:37:17] [SSH] Starting sftp client.
[01/25/24 01:37:17] [SSH] Copying latest remoting.jar...
Source agent hash is 2E3A82C4A7B2851BCCA33BDFC24E223C. Installed agent hash is 2E3A82C4A7B2851BCCA33BDFC24E223C
Verified agent jar. No update is necessary.
Expanded the channel window size to 4MB
[01/25/24 01:37:44] [SSH] Starting agent process: cd "/home/gautashe" && /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.9-0.3.ea.el8.x86_64  -jar remoting.jar -workDir /home/gautashe -jar-cache /home/gautashe/remoting/jarCache
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.9-0.3.ea.el8.x86_64: No such file or directory
Agent JVM has terminated. Exit code=127
```

have tried to reinstall JDK, restart Jenkins and check the directory paths are valid.